# How to create this long shortcode by using a foreach loop (PHP + Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, shortcode

Can anyone help me create a shortcode such as the one below by using a foreach loop?

The purpose of this shortcode is to generate a playlist, and uses opening and closing tags:

```
[zoomsounds id="favorites_playlist"] [/zoomsounds]
```

In between those tags, each song that is to be added to the playlist gets its own shortcode, like this:

```
[zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist" source="'.$source.'" type="detect" songname="'.$title.'" init_player="off" play_target="footer"]
```

So let's say a user has 2 songs in their playlist, the entire shortcode would look something like this:

```
[zoomsounds id="favorites_playlist"][zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist" source="http://www.test.com/sound/brobob.mp3" type="detect" songname="Song 1" init_player="off" play_target="footer"][zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist" source="http://www.test.com/sound/brobob2.mp3" type="detect" songname="Song 2" init_player="off" play_target="footer"][/zoomsounds]
```

As you can see, each song's shortcode comes one after another, enclosed in the start/close tags.

---

The easiest way I thought I could do this was to use a foreach loop to generate each song's shortcode. Here is the simple function I wrote.

```
function streamFavoritesPlaylist() {
    $favs[] = get_user_favorites();

    echo do_shortcode('[zoomsounds id="favorites_playlist"]');
        foreach ($favs[0] as $fav) {
            $title = get_the_title($fav);
            $post = get_post($fav);
            $post_slug = $post->post_name;
            $source = '.../mp3/'.$post_slug.'.mp3';
            $song_name = get_the_title($fav);

            echo do_shortcode('[zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist" source="'.$source.'" type="detect" songname="'.$title.'" init_player="off" play_target="footer"]');
        }
    echo do_shortcode('[/zoomsounds]');
}
```

And this is the result that I get.
[image]

Clearly this is the wrong way to go about doing something like this. Not to mention, the closing tag did not take, and instead has been displayed in text. Perhaps this is why the entire thing is not working?

I should mention that by using the entire shortcode on it's own works fine. It's only when I try to build the shortcode in this manner does it not work.

How would you suggest I go about accomplishing something like this? Thanks a lot.

---

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for everyone's input. This is what I came up with, which is similar to what @DACrosby posted, and @TheManiac suggested.

```
function streamFavoritesPlaylist() {
    $favs[] = get_user_favorites();
    $shortcode_full = "";

    foreach ($favs[0] as $fav) {
        $title = get_the_title($fav);
        $post = get_post($fav);
        $post_slug = $post->post_name;
        $source = '.../mp3/'.$post_slug.'.mp3';
        $song_name = get_the_title($fav);
        $shortcode = '[zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist" source="'.$source.'" type="detect" songname="'.$title.'" init_player="off" play_target="footer"]';

        $shortcode_full .= $shortcode;
    }

    return '[zoomsounds id="favorites_playlist"]'.$shortcode_full.'[/zoomsounds]';
}
```

And where I actually need the shortcode generated, I am using:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(streamFavoritesPlaylist()); ?>
```

It's working perfectly. Thanks again, community.

Comment: I might not be following but I don't think you should be using `do_shortcode` if you're just trying to generate the shortcode text. Generate the code in its entirety as a single string, then call `do_shortcode` on the result.

Comment: @TheManiac That makes perfect sense. Let me try it out. Any chance you could give me a quick snippet? Either way, thank you!

Comment: Looks like DACrosby already made a snippet for ya. Pretty sure he's got it right.

Comment: @TheManiac Yep, pretty much what I came up with after your suggestion. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not working because `[/zoomsounds]` isn't a shortcode - it's the closing tag of one. So running the first `[zoomsounds ...]` and the closing `[/zoomsounds]` separately doesn't work as expected. Like TheManiac mentioned in a comment, try building the string first then having just one `do_shortcode`

```
function streamFavoritesPlaylist() {
    $favs[] = get_user_favorites();
    $str = '[zoomsounds id="favorites_playlist"]';

    foreach ($favs[0] as $fav) {
        $title = get_the_title($fav);
        $post = get_post($fav);
        $post_slug = $post->post_name;
        $source = '.../mp3/'.$post_slug.'.mp3';
        $song_name = get_the_title($fav);

        $str .= '[zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist"'
              . ' source="'.$source.'" type="detect"'
              . ' songname="'.$title.'" init_player="off"'
              . ' play_target="footer"]';
    }
    $str .= '[/zoomsounds]';
    echo do_shortcode( $str );
}
```

Comment: I had actually worked this out on my end before I saw your comment, but this is pretty much what I did. I'll post my code in my post. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just took your sample code with a simple for loop to print out the result, and it works.

It seems to be some of the string values contains special characters (e.g.: / ' "")

You could check the string values or use some sample code below to test the method.

```
echo do_shortcode('[zoomsounds id="favorites_playlist"]');
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
            $title = "FAV ".$i;
            $post = "FAV ".$i;
            $post_slug = "FAV ".$i;
            $source = "FAV ".$i;
            $song_name = "FAV ".$i;

            echo do_shortcode('[zoomsounds_player config="favorites-playlist" source="'.$source.'" type="detect" songname="'.$title.'" init_player="off" play_target="footer"]');
        }
echo do_shortcode('[/zoomsounds]');
```

And the print out:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ugGt.png)

Hope this would help.

Comment: Interesting, let me check this out and I'll let you know how it goes. Also, how did you print that out? Thanks!

Comment: I used a simple custom plugin and add this method into my custom plugin, and printed it out on my custom template.